# Group operation causes performance problems

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

This is the query, and more precisely speaking group operation, that causes performance problems:

```
db.documentBilling.aggregate([{ "$match" : 
{ "$and" : [ { "startDate" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2016-09-19T22:00:00.000Z"), "$lt" : ISODate("2021-04-06T13:13:23.618Z")}} , 
{ "externalId.value" : { "$not" : { "$regex" : "TEST_DOCUMENT/"}}, "type" : { "$in" : [ "DEFAULT"]}}]}},
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$status" , "total" : { "$sum" : 1}}},
{ "$project" : { "total" : 1 , "_id" : 0 , "status" : "$_id"}}, 
{ "$sort" : { "status" : -1 , "total" : -1}}
])
```

I have an index on 'startDate' field. Adding combined index with any or all other fields from match operation (externalId.value, type) doesn't help at all.

Do you know how can I speed up this query?

I also can change the structure of this collections so it looks different.

Comment: How much data are you querying? You can know the index usage by running the `explain` on the query and generated query plan shows the details.

Comment: I am querying almost half a million of documents here.

Comment: Have you considered using a compound index which has other fields in the `$match` stage? See [Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/) for some ideas.